# Recipe Item cannot be deleted/ removed from principle Item

Tags: items

Recipe item cannot be deleted/ removed from principle item
Item: 6001324283043
Recipe Item: 913
When deleting the recipe item and closing the menu after saving, the recipe item reverts and is automatically re-added to item 6001324283043 without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

1. Select Stock
2. Select Recipe
3. Select item 6001324283043
4. Delete pack 913 and save
5. Close all menus’
6. Log-out and Close Winbranch
7. Open Winbranch
8. Select System
9. Select Diagnostics
10. Enable Full Internal Diagnostics & Additional Diagnostics
11. Select Run